# Get one object in a set of objects by property name in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, properties, set

I have an NSSet which holds a bunch of Detail objects in it.  Each Detail object has .name and .text properties.  I would like to find one particular Detail in the set where .name = "memo" and see what's being held in its .text property.

How on earth do I do this?

(.indexOf won't work.  I don't now if I need to use find and .map somehow, or if there's a means of direct accessing that one particular object in Swift.)

For clarity, I'm using Core Data and each of my "Event" objects has a relationship to many Detail objects.  The NSSet of Details is the set that I'm getting off a given Event.

Again, here's what it looks like:

> Detail object has properties
>
> .name
>
> .text

I get the details from the active "event" like this:

```
var someDetails: NSSet()?
someDetails = event.details!
```

So now I have the set of details for that event.

Now I want to access the detail object whose .name = "memo" and see what it's .text property is.

Creating the details themselves was much easier as all I had to do was create the detail managed object, assign its properties, and add it to a set.  When the set had all the objects I needed, I just assigned it to the event.details and saved back to Core Data.  I never dreamed it would be much harder to access an individual "detail".

I have no idea what to do next for direct access.

Am I stuck looping through the set, looking at each object, and pulling out the one I want?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You should use `Set` instead of `NSSet`, however I will answer you question about `NSSet`.

I imagine you have a class like this

```
class Detail: NSObject {
    let name: String
    let text: String

    init(name: String, text: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.text = text
    }
}
```

and an `NSSet` like this

```
let details = NSSet(array: [
    Detail(name: "a", text: "1"),
    Detail(name: "b", text: "2"),
    Detail(name: "c", text: "3"),
    Detail(name: "d", text: "4")]
    )
```

now you want all the elms where `name` is `"a"`, then write

```
let results =  details.flatMap { $0 as? Detail }.filter { $0.name == "a" }
```

and finally print them

```
for result in results {
    print(result.text)
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!